# Stripe and nodejs extend subscription expiration date on upgrade subscription

Tags: node.js, next.js, stripe-payments, subscription

I'm using nodejs and stripe api to upgrade current user subscription to a new subscription.
I want to extend current expiration date of subscription to a new date after upgrading subscription.

Current case:

Currently, its updating subscription to a new one, but expiration date remains the same as the one before.

What I want:

I want to get new expiration date from the date subscription is updated.

Code:

```js
   const currentSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
     currentSubscriptionId
    )

    const updatedSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.update(
      currentSubscriptionId,
      {
        payment_behavior: 'pending_if_incomplete',
        proration_behavior: 'always_invoice',
        items: [
          {
            id: currentSubscription.items.data[0].id,
            price: newPriceId,
          },
        ],
      }
    )
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Calculate the new end date based on the current date and billing period of the new plan. Then, set the trial end date of the updated subscription to the calculated expiration date.